# Ajax response isn't responding to a json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The task is very simple I only need to save these json responses into my code to manipulate it later but I can't get to make it function. I've tried more than a strategy with nothing working. Thing is it's working for a json and not the other with the exact same syntax. Here is my code

```js
function searchOwner() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://elvet.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/get_pet_owner?pet_id=p12345678912345",
    success: function(responseData) {
      alert(responseData)
    }
  })
}

function searchPet() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://elvet.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/getpets?pet_id=p12345678912345",
    success: function(responseData) {
      alert('ok')
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The SearchOwner is not working at all while searchPet is working just fine. Any help would be highly appreciated thank you

Comment: Not the exact same calls... the `searchPet` has datatype of `jsonp` - why not just `json` like the previous call?

Comment: [In order for a question to be answered, it must specify what exactly is wrong. Stating simply that “it doesn’t work” is not sufficient.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: code seems to work fine above when they are run

Comment: The `get_pet_owner` url doesn't seem to return `jsonp` but the other does. It is returning standard json and is not CORS enabled

Comment: @charlietfl its returning this error :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://elvet.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/get_pet_owner?pet_id=p12345678912345' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Yes I realize that. The two endpoints don't work the same. Is that your back end or is it a third party?

Answer (score -1):

`dataType : "json",` in `searchOwner()` where as it's `dataType: 'jsonp'` in `searchPet()`

Comment: yes that was a typo mistake as I was trying different solutions.json will never work it's supposed to be jsonp I've already edited it thanks for pointing it out.